# Using JavaCV and Realm together causes "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java, android, realm, javacv

I have recently been getting the following error by attempting to start an instance of JavaCV's FFmpegFrameGrabber:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:413)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:381)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2597)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:386)
    at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:380)...
```

While solutions to this problem exist, none worked for me.

Through many trials i have discovered that weirdly enough, if i do not include Realm in my project, i no longer receive this error.

Here is the part of my build.gradle file in which I include all of these libraries:

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.0.0-1.1', classifier: 'android-x86'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-arm'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.8.1-1.1', classifier: 'android-x86'

// ORM
compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.2' // Tested NOT OK - Causes JavaCV to crash
//
```

I am thinking that there may be a solution to this problem that i am not aware of. I found no mention anywhere on the internet about library incompatibility or why this behaviour may occur.

I will edit this post with any additional details that anyone might need.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I attempted to apply the fix described [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq).
Now my packaging options look like this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/ffmpeg/pom.xml'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/opencv/pom.xml'

    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"
}
```

Unfortunately, this change has no effect. I'm still stuck.

Comment: I wonder if this has anything to do with the `32-bit 64-bit` native library problem that is referenced in the FAQ for Realm.

Comment: If you are reffering to the "Couldn’t Load “librealm-jni.so” then you may be onto someting. I will try the solution provided in the FAQ and report back.

Comment: This sounds very much like a 32-bit vs. 64 bit issue like mentioned by @EpicPandaForce: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq See "Couldn’t Load “librealm-jni.so”". Realm provides binaries for both 32-bit and 64-bit but if other libraries doesn't do the same, Android will potentially load the wrong versions crashing your app. There is a work-around in the FAQ

Comment: I have updated my answer per @EpicPandaForce's suggestion. It had no effect however. I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 and Nexus 5X, both of which are 32 bit devices to my knowledge.

Comment: Hey @ChristianMelchior, i have tried the fix suggested in the FAQ but the error remains the same. I double checked and the 5X is indeed 64 bit, however the Galaxy S4 is not and suffers from the same issue. Any advice would be really helpfull

Comment: I would try to open the dex file and see which `.so` files are actually shipped. That might give you some hints to what library is causing the problems.

Comment: I'm going to need more info on how exactly to do that. I have never worked with dex files before...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of one of my coleagues i have been able to solve this issue.

In adition to the steps described in the question, we:

- Copyed all of the .so files in the *app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi* and *app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a* folders
- Added

  ndk {
          abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
      }

  to the *defaultConfig* part of the module's *build.gradle* file
- Added

  lintOptions {
      abortOnError false
  }

  to the *android* part of the module's *build.gradle* file

I will try to provide further clarifications to anyone that needs them if i am able.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this issue occurs because of Gradle doesn't resolve dependencies properly from maven profile ..In my case only x86 depdendecies shipped to APK. that means code above works only on x86 cpu architecture. solution should be done on Android Studio. but as workaround I did this:

1. Download binary [javacv-platform-1.3.1-bin.zip](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/bytedeco/javacv-platform/1.3.1/javacv-platform-1.3.1-bin.zip). It's from: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv
2. Inside directory **javacv-bin** copy these jars to new directory

   1. ffmpeg-android-arm.jar
   2. opencv-android-arm.jar
   3. ffmpeg-android-x86.jar
   4. opencv-android-x86.jar
3. For 2.1 2.2 files,  Extract these jars and go to **lib** then or **armeabi**. Then copy all `*.so` files into your project under:

   1. `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/`
   2. `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/`
4. you might do the same with 2.3 * 2.4 jars by copying dependencies into `app/src/main/jniLibs/x86/` . just check your `apk` if it really doesn't have them.

That's it.

Comment: I guess there is nothing wrong with gradle, `javacv` just has only two architectures (armeabi, x86) while e.g. `opencv4android` has more (armeabi, "armeabi-v7a, "x86, mips - and even more for x64 for opencv 3.*). So of course other folders will be empty if these .so files doesn't even exist on the internet

Comment: That is exactly the issue .. if you have one directory for any CPU architecture. System will look for native lib in that directory only. so you need to copy libs from other compatible libs or delete this directory.got it ?