# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil in start FFmpegFrameGrabber

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

i have creating slowmotion video app in android and i can try to set video motion speed in any start and ending postion in total video length.

but some error occur in start FFmpegFrameGrabber.

here my code:

```
private class PrepareMedia extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private PrepareMedia() {
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(viewSource);
        try {
            grabber.start();
            grabber.stop();
            grabber.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground: ");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

view my error.

```
01-12 15:59:16.374 14990-14990/com.example.slowmotiondemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.slowmotiondemo, PID: 14990
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.bytedeco.javacpp.avutil
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:585)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:530)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avformat$AVFormatContext.<clinit>(avformat.java:2819)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.startUnsafe(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:468)
        at org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber.start(FFmpegFrameGrabber.java:462)
        at com.example.slowmotiondemo.ActivityCutMergeVideo.prepareMediaForOreantation(ActivityCutMergeVideo.java:687)
        at com.example.slowmotiondemo.ActivityCutMergeVideo.onCreate(ActivityCutMergeVideo.java:507)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

please tell me how to solve error.

Comment: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/133

Comment: Possible answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35088655/5154891

Answer (score 1):

Firstly try manual installation of the javacv (https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv#manual-installation).

Then try to extract .so files from jar and put them into app/src/main/jniLibs.

If that also will not work, then use this manual: 
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/wiki/The-UnsatisfiedLinkError-X-File-%28a-real-experience%29